# Issues when working with multiple screens (mixed HiDPI and non-HiDPI)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I'm using a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 with the latest Windows 10 Pro (version 1607). It has a HiDPI screen with 2736 x 1824 resolution and is set to display text, apps etc. at a scale 200%. This works ok with most apps. Everything has a reasonable size and text is very crisp.

Additonally, I've connected a 21" with 1920 x 1080 resolution, set to display text, apps etc. at a scale 100%. This is were the problems start. Most apps seem to be unable to work with two screens set to different display scales.

Didn't I setup the system correctly? Or are Windows 10 and most applications still not fully ready for HiDPI displays?

Experience with apps:

- Microsoft Word, Excel, Outlook, OneNote 2016: mostly ok, splash screen is always at 100%
- Microsoft PowerPoint 2016, Internet Explorer, Adobe Reader: runs at 200% on both screens, therefore the UI elements on the second screen are far too big
- Firefox: when moving a window from one screen to the other, most of the window becomes white and the HTML page is only displayed in a small better; resizing the window fixes it.
- Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Windows File Explorer: no major issues seen so far
- Windows Display Settings: The overview at the top doesn't show the real size of the screen but a size derived from the resolution. Therefore the Surface Pro 4 screen looks much bigger than the 21" screen even though it's the opposite round.
- All apps: When a window is positioned such that it partially covers both screens at the same time, it has a invalid size on one of the screens (either double or half the size it's supposed to be)

I have been working with a similar setup with a MacBook Pro Retina for 5 years and I didn't have any of these issues. And it was much better a remembering the size and position of windows when connecting and unconnecting different secondary screens.

Comment: I suppose you have the latest aniversary update installed. One part of the problem is that the technology used in those apps just differs and the support of DPI scaling is different - WinForms is very different from WPF apps etc. So it is necessary to distinguish OS problems from development framework related problems.

Comment: Yes, I have the lasted update installed (version 1607). But I don't care how they implement it. This can't be rocket science. HiDPI screens have now been available for at least 5 years. That should be sufficient time to come a with a working solution.

Comment: But you cannot blame OS for errors in individual apps and/or their frameworks, seems like only the last two points apply to the OS itself.

Comment: On the Mac, there were initially a few apps that looked a bit blurry because they run in a compatiblity mode as far as screen resolution was concerned. But all other issues were solved by the OS. And the apps were quickly fixed. Compare this to Windows were both the OS and most apps still have issues, even after this long time. And as far as Microsoft Office is concerned, it seems moot to discuss which department at Microsoft is to blame.